# Убрать разделение последней недели в году, при понедельном чтении данных из БД SQLite

Tags: sqlite, python-3.x

Есть база входящих телефонных номеров:

ID(Уникальный) | Дата | Неделя | Департамент | Номер телефона

Пример строк:

```
('201604231905293465628284551', '2016-04-23', 16, 'zch', 89110145664)
```

Нужно строить график по количеству уникальных номеров за 50 недель (по неделям). Для этого делаю такой запрос:

```
c.execute("SELECT count(DISTINCT num) FROM calls WHERE department == (?) AND datetime LIKE '{}%' AND week == (?)".format(year), (dept, week))
```

Так как в базе данные за несколько лет, то нужно указать и номер недели и год.

Проблема возникает в последней неделе года, т.к. она часть недели может быть в одном году, а другая часть в другом. При таком запросе получается, что на выходе вместо 50 значений, я получаю 51 значение (последняя неделя выводится дважды со значением за один и второй год). Для построения графика мне нужно суммировать два значения этой недели в одно.

Как это лучше сделать? 
Возможно ли это сделать в SQL - запросе?

Comment: в mysql есть функция `WEEK(date,first)` можно в забросе сгруппировать по номеру недеи

Comment: В данном случае поле дата отвечает не за дату добавления в базу, а дату самого звонка (это текст). Как я понял week будет работать только в первом варианте.

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему иначе.
Решил не привязываться к календарным неделям, а вручную указывать промежутки по датам. Для этого переписал запрос следующим образом:

```
c.execute("SELECT count(DISTINCT num) FROM calls WHERE department == (?) AND datetime BETWEEN (?) AND (?)",(dept, day_start, day_end))
```